# users (except come from createsuperuser) cannot login to web app

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have registration page and login page. Users who registrated cannot login in login page. It always return else block which is redirecting HttpResponse('error'). Could you please help me?
note: users successfully registrated (can be seen in database) and they are all active users.
note2: only users who created from createsuperuser can login at login.html. others cannot.

in views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:home'))

        else:
            print("error")
            return HttpResponse('error')

    else:
        return render(request, 'auth/login.html', {})
```

in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from users import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

in login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Login {% endblock %}

{% block head %} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <h1>You have already signed in</h1>
        {% else %}
            <h2>Login Page</h2>
            <form action="{% url 'users:login' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"><br>
                <br>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is how I create users in views.py:

```
def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        registration_form = SignUpForm(data=request.POST)

        if registration_form.is_valid():
            user = registration_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            registered = True

        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h2>Try again</h2>')
        
    else:
        registration_form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'auth/register.html', {
        'registration_form': registration_form,
        'registered': registered
    })
```

register.html

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% if registered %}
        <h2>Thanks for registering :)))</h2>
    {% else %}
        <h1>Registration</h1>
        <p>You can easily join us by completing the form below!</p>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ registration_form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=24, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name', 'style': 'width: 300px;', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=256, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username', 'style': 'width: 300px;', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, help_text='(Enter valid email adress)', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'style': 'width: 300px;', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password', 'style': 'width: 300px;', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password again', 'style': 'width: 300px;', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    field_order = ['name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

I would be grateful if anyone help me.

I tried all the way that I know to solve my problem. But I couldn't solve. Actually same codes work in my another projects. But I am suffering from same issue in my last two projects. For that reason, I need help of community.

Comment: How do you *create* (register) users? Very likely the password is not hashed properly.

Comment: I just added register function in views.py and also register.html @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: and the `SignUpForm`?

Comment: just added forms.py @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Your form will never set the password, since `password1` is *not* a field name...